# Use a popover in a ForEach loop (Swift/SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, foreach, popover

I'm working on an app in which there are several buttons in a VStack, and each of them should have their own popover when clicked on. However, when I click on each button, the popover does not appear.

The code I've tried is below. I should mention that I'm **very** new to Swift/SwiftUI. Again, when I click on each button (which is a ZStack), it seems like the click is registered but nothing appears. If anyone could help, that would be great! Thanks so much!

```swift
struct TodayView: View {
    @State var showingPopover: Bool
    
    init() {
        getAccess()
        courses = getEvents(name: "Home") //name should be "All Classes"
        showingPopover = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                background
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(courses, id: \.self) { course in
                            Button {
                                showingPopover = true
                            } label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    Image("event_img")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                    Text(course.title)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                        .font(.system(size: 28))
                                }
                            }
                            .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                               Text("Hello")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Today")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach to display a popover for the desired selected `Course`. Using a `.popover(item: $selectedCourse)` outside the `ForEach` loop.

The example code assumes that your array `courses` consists of type `Course` elements.

```
struct TodayView: View {
    // for testing
    @State var courses = ....
    @State var selectedCourse: Course?  // <-- here
    
    init() {
         getAccess()
         courses = getEvents(name: "Home") //name should be "All Classes"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                background
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(courses, id: \.self) { course in
                            Button {
                                selectedCourse = course // <-- here
                            } label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    Image("event_img")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                    Text(course.title)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                        .font(.system(size: 28))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .popover(item: $selectedCourse) { course in  // <-- here
                Text(course.title)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Today")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

to use `EKEvent` as courses,

add this to make `EKEvent` Identifiable:

```
extension EKEvent: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self.eventIdentifier }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I do not have a "Course" class in my code. Is there another solution you could think of? Sorry, I am a very early beginner in Swift/SwiftUI. Thanks!

Comment: what is in your `courses` array? Replace `Course` of `selectedCourse` with that type.

Comment: Oh, ok... that makes sense. They're EKEvents, so I've replaced selectedCourse with that data type. However, I'm still getting an error: Instance method 'popover(item:attachmentAnchor:arrowEdge:content:)' requires that 'EKEvent' conform to 'Identifiable'. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: updated my answer. Will re-work it with`EKEvent` shortly.

Comment: FYI This code will not point the popover arrow into the correct button.